# Prevent DataGrid row from being deleted

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I want to protect some rows of a DataGrid to be protected from deletion by the user, although the property `CanUserDeleteRows` is set to `true`.

Is there a possibility to protect some rows, hopefully through a databinding or a trigger? The ItemsSource is bound to an ObservableCollection of T.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have a property on your bound objects that can be used to determine if the current row can be deleted , like 'IsDeleteEnabled', then you can bind the DataGrid's CanUserDeleteRows property to SelectedItem.IsDeleteEnabled.

For example,

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" 
        CanUserDeleteRows="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1, Path=SelectedItem.IsDeleteEnabled}"
```

Comment: +1 Good idea, but it will only work if multi selection is disabled. I will test if it works because I think it a nice solution, but I depend on multi selection and for this it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Never done this with a DataGrid.  Usually, when I need to control something like this, I use a ListBox and a DataTemplate with a Grid within to give it the idea of a Grid or a ListView with a GridView in the template because they both give you more control over the interaction.

A shot in the dark, since you're binding, you could use a DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate and make your own Delete button/text which is visible or enabled based off logic within your binding object.  Maybe something like this (I didn't test this, but it should be a direction you can head)?

```
<dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action">
    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Text Content="Delete" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ButtonEnabled="{Binding Path=IsDeleteEnabled, Mode=OneWay}" Content="Delete" Command="{Binding Path=DeleteMe}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Using this method, since the command is bound to the individual object, you would probably have to raise an event your screen's ViewModel handles to remove that row from the ObservableCollection.

Again, not sure if this is the best way, but it's my 10 minute stab at it.  So if it's horrible, please don't vote me down too much.

Comment: My interest in this question is, if there is a possibility to do it with the integrated deletion features of the DataGrid without implementing my own deletion handling. But thanks anyhow for your answer.